# How can I check is there any number in series and count any number(float,integer etc)?

Tags: python

Here is my code:
I check number with isnumeric() function but it only return integer number is there any other way to count any number(it doesn't matter if it is integer or float) in series?

```
def check_number(item):
    try:
        num1=float(item)
    except:
        return 'Not number'
       

series=input('Enter a series of numbers separated by a space:').split()
count_numbers=0
count_non_numeric=0
for item in series:
    print(check_number(item))
    if item.isnumeric():
        count_numbers+=1
    else:
        count_non_numeric+=1
print('Amount of numbers: ',count_numbers)
print('Amount of non-numeric values: ',count_non_numeric)
```

I try to write it with the try and except and create check_number() function but I couldn't get the result that I want. I want my program to check the series if there isn't any number then my program return "no number" else it returns nothing.

Comment: Your `try` branch doesn't return anything?

Comment: İt did. I want it to check all the data and if there is no number in the list then return not numeric but it checks one by one.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It looks like you haven't returned anything in your function. This change should make your program work:

```
def check_number(item):
    try:
        return float(item)
    except:
        return 'Not number'
```

I have just replaced your variable assignment with a return statement.

Comment: The function should return None or the same types.